# tuple of tuple of dict from mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, tuples

I am running MySQL query from python that returning tuple of dict, lets call it result. Now each dict has 3 key/value pairs as an element, one of these 3 element is date. Now I want to create "tuple of tuple of dict" something like

```
(({},{},{}..),({},{},{}..),({},{},{}..)...)
```

where each inner tuple represent the data of the same date. I know i can use dict comprehension. But am looking for more elegant way to do this. How can I do this in most efficient way ?

Comment: Would be easier if you give a real sample input and expected output

Comment: Do you have to keep them in a tuple of tuples?

Comment: khajvah@ not necessary. It can be anything what I want is the group of dictionaries on the basis of date.

Answer (score 1):

One good looking solution would be to store them inside a dictionary:

```
>>> t = ({"a":2}, {"a":2}, {"a":3})
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in t:
...     d[i['a']].append(i)
...
```

Now, this is obviously not what you want but this is better than creating the list of lists inside a loop directly in terms of speed, also a dictionary seems to be a better fit for this kind of data. This can also be converted to whatever you want easily:

```
>>> [k for c,k in d.items()]
[[{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}], [{'a': 3}]]
```

If the speed is critical, you can sort the db results by date, in which case you can get a better algorithm.

Comment: Yes the whole aim to do this is reducing the time. So can you please suggest me which algorithm I should go for? if i get the data order by date from database.

Comment: @MahendraVishwakarma Try this one first. This should be fast enough.

Comment: This I have already tried. This way I have to iterate millions of records and I don't want to iterate all the records. Because iterating millions of records is time consuming.

Comment: this is kind of an XY problem. It hard to say what would be the best solution for you. Maybe it's not processing millions of records at one go? It's impossible to find a best solution for you without any insite.  As far as this question goes, this answer, answers your question