# how to join the same dictionary element together python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one dictionarylist which looks like this:

```
 [{'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '184'}, 
{'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '29'}, 
{'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '31'},
 {'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '12'},
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '12'}, 
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '15'}, 
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '184'}, 
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '858'}, 
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '51'},
 {'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '102'}]
```

how to change the dictionarylist into the format such as

```
[{'queryID': '1','documentID':'184','29','31','12'},
{'queryID': '2','documentID':'12','15','184','858','51','102}]
```

Comment: The expected output is not valid dictionary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40783207/1527217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to group a list of dictionaries by `queryID` key and get a list of `documentID`s for each group.
 The expected output, in such case, should contain a sequence of `documentID`s 
Use the following approach with `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter` functions:

```
import itertools, operator

l = [{'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '184'},
{'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '29'},
{'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '31'},
 {'queryID': '1', 'documentID': '12'},
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '12'},
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '15'},
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '184'},
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '858'},
{'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '51'},
 {'queryID': '2', 'documentID': '102'}]

l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('queryID'))

result = [{'queryID': k, 'documentID': [d['documentID'] for d in v ]}
          for k,v in itertools.groupby(l, key=operator.itemgetter('queryID'))]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'documentID': ['184', '29', '31', '12'], 'queryID': '1'}, {'documentID': ['12', '15', '184', '858', '51', '102'], 'queryID': '2'}]
```